# Submit with value in button verse input (PhpED behaviour)

Tags: php, html, forms, post, phped

I have the following forms.  I would have expected identical results for both forms (except for the data value of course).

Is there anything wrong with the second form and its use of a button with the name/value pair?

The reason I ask is when running the code using PhpED IDE, it responds with the value of `$_POST['task2']` equal to "SUBMIT" and not "save".

EDIT.  Upon further investigation, I have found that IE7 (emulated using IE 10) has the same behavior.  That being the case, it seems bad practice to use a button with name/pair if you care about IE7.  True?

```
<?php
echo('<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>');
?>
<form method='post' action='' name='form1'>
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="task1" value="save" />
    <input type="text" name="data1" value="test1" />
</form>

<form method='post' action='' name='form2'>
    <button type="submit" name="task2" value="save">SUBMIT</button>
    <input type="text" name="data2" value="test2" />
</form>
```

Comment: may be because you have both of the buttons to `SUBMIT` ? I mean with `task2` you did also `<button type="submit" name="task2" value="save">SUBMIT</button>`

Comment: @Begueradj  Each form is unique, and doesn't interact.  Assuming there is nothing wrong with using a submit button with a name, maybe just a bug in PhpED?

Comment: Yes, it really could be a bug with your IDE. I never use IDEs because for big projects they often trigger unexpected behavior. I suggest you to run your code using WAMP server or something like that instead this IDE

Comment: @Begueradj  It appears to be the browser, and not the IDE (except that the IDE appears to use an embedded IE7 browser which is not ideal).  See my edited post.

Comment: what is strange is that your `value="save"` in both forms. It is really so strange that you get SUBMIT value which is not event present in this code (or may be you have to check your original code)

Comment: @Begueradj  "SUBMIT" is the text in the second button tag.

Comment: I run your code as you posted it and it displays me the right value (save).

Comment: @Begueradj  Run it using IE7, and you will see something different.

Comment: I am sorry, I never used in my life Microsoft products. I tested your code on Opera, Chrome and Firefox. So  this problem is likely to be related to your IE and maybe in conjunction to your IDE.

Comment: @Begueradj  I don't use IE, but I test it.  Also, even without using the IDE, I experience the same effect, so it is definitely a IE thing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As a web developer it is a good practice to test different browsers as you are doing.